# Creating a share from machine A on machine B (Windows)?

Tags: windows, server-message-block, share

Say I have a share \\MachineA\Share.

Now I get a second machine, MachineB. All shares will be moved from MachineA to MachineB. But for the sake of backward compatibility I want all shares by the name of \\MachineA\Share to continue working.

How can I do this? I've tried sharing a share in Explorer (not allowed) and I've tried creating a symlink to the share and sharing the symlink (is allowed, but yields "Device not ready" when trying to access the share).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't redirect a share like that in Windows. It'd be possible to hack it together with Linux, but not a good idea at all.

This is the primary reason I recommend even small businesses with one file server to use [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_(Microsoft)). So that when the server or share names change, it's no big deal.

Comment: Yeah, that would have been a good idea, unfortunately I didn't set up MachineA. So there are no options?

Comment: Well if there is no MachineA, why not just name the new one "MachineA"?

Comment: OR better create a DNS entry of machineA to point to MachineB's IP address. Obviously MachineA ahs to be renamed machineC

Answer (score 0):

You may try to deploy a custom "hosts" file to the clients who use the share in order to make "MachineA" netbios name point to the IP of "MachineB".

Answer (score 0):

Like others have said above, this cannot be done. I would recommend dropping a shortcut in \MachineA\share\ that points to \MachineB\share. That way if someone does not have their own shortcut / drive mapping updated the only thing they'll find is a shortcut to the proper network resource. Alternatively you could drop a text file in there that tells folks to contact yourself.